# svn: Checksum mismatch in Lotus Domino SVN

Tags: svn, lotus-notes

I'm using SVN into Lotus Domino Designer.

I can't resolve this error:

> svn: Checksum mismatch for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Lotus\Notes\Data\workspace\aed-documenti1005.nsf\Resources\Applets\aaa.applet'; expected: 'f8a0e3681335d0eeaad2ac23c085aa5f', actual: '74bb3c3cc12d20459b5696e1b11d7414'

trying to commit the resource.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to update before commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried to update, revert from SVN ecc. (doesn't resolve), i solved in this way:

- deleted local folder for the entire project
- made a Checkout command from SVN